# Not able to populate EXTERNAL TABLE in snowflake with DELTA FORMAT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, delta-lake

I have an external stage @STG_AZURE_BLOB/frankfurt/arv/ in snowflake which has data files as parquet format, and it also contains _delta_log folder with .json file(metadata). I am trying to create an external table of a DELTA FORMAT in snowflake which will hold these parquet files.

With the below code I am trying to create an external table. The .json file has all the information wrt to the delta table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE delta_prdc_arv_time_cr (
  part_date VARCHAR AS SPLIT_PART(metadata$filename, '/', 6)

)
PARTITION BY (part_date)
LOCATION = @STG_AZURE_BLOB/frankfurt/arv/
FILE_FORMAT = (
  TYPE = 'PARQUET'
)
TABLE_FORMAT = 'DELTA'
AUTO_REFRESH = FALSE
 REFRESH_ON_CREATE=FALSE
```

The table gets successfully created but it doesn't have any data. When I list the stage, it does shows me all the files.

Am I missing something here to get the data pushed in the external table?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh it at least once `ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE delta_prdc_arv_time_cr REFRESH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external table was not refreshed during creation `REFRESH_ON_CREATE=FALSE` so it should be refreshed at least once to see initial files:

```
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE delta_prdc_arv_time_cr REFRESH;
```

---

Metadata [EXTERNAL_TABLE_FILES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/external_table_files)

> This table function can be used to query information about the staged data files included in the metadata for a specified external table.
>
> ```
> select *
> from table(information_schema.external_table_files(TABLE_NAME=>'MYTABLE'));
> ```